# Java Object Creation while inhertance

Tags: java, methods, overriding

If I have two classes:

```java
Apple extends Fruit
```

I see sometimes there is:

```java
Fruit ob= new Apple();
```

What is this, please?

Comment: That is polymorphism https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: I'm not sure this is programming to an interface necessarily - could be plain old inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: @topsail -- yes. you are right. Dupe targets changed.